# Firebase change activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I change data in Firebase database, my activity switches to MainActivity for no reason. I would like to go Register2 activity after I have made change in firebasedatabase . Yet most of the times MainActivity pop up.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recording_);
    init_xml();

    auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userdatabaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");

    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            save_user_information_to_database();
        }
    });



}

protected void save_user_information_to_database() {
    if(auth.getCurrentUser()==null){
        Toast.makeText(Recording_Activity.this,"Out of service",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    String userid=auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String usernamedata=username.getText().toString();
    String namedata=name.getText().toString();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(usernamedata) || TextUtils.isEmpty(namedata)){
        Toast.makeText(Recording_Activity.this,"Username or Name can not be empty",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

    }else{
        User_Info user_info=new User_Info(userid,usernamedata,namedata);
        Toast.makeText(Recording_Activity.this,"daaaaaaaa",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userid)
                .setValue(new User_Info(userid,usernamedata,namedata));
        startActivity(new Intent(Recording_Activity.this,Recording_Activity2.class));
    }

}
```

`

Comment: So you are redirected to the `Register2` activity on button click, right?

Comment: Most of the times MainActivity pops up, and if main activity pops up, it won't be redirected  Register2Activity. Yet, sometimes Register2 activity pops up directly just like I have wanted. I know, it's interesting,  but when ı tried to upload an image to my firebase storage in another activity, the same thing happens and it will go Main Activity. I feel like any changes in firebase send me to MainActivity.